# AngularJs setPristine() not reseting invalid flag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could anyone help with the the included Plunker??

Simply submit form with only one required field entered. This will trigger the validation errors. Then reset the form which calls both setPristine and setUntouched - both of which are supposed to reset the form however neither clear the validation errors?

I want the form to be cleared of data but also no validation messages to be shown (even though I appreciate as the data is blank it is in fact invalid)

i.e. this reset function

```
$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.newQuestion = angular.copy(tempQuestion);

    $scope.forms.setPristine();
    $scope.forms.setUntouched();
};
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/y8J6A7Xzf4MH57NeGuUB)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are calling the setPristine() & setUntouched() incorrectly.

   Correct syntax is `formName.$setPristine()` and `formName.$setUntouched()`

   See [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) for more details
2. Since you are setting `attempted=true` in the , when you want to reset    the form, you must reset the value of `attempted` as well. This will ensure that  the `ng-if` re-evaluates and does not render the error message.

So the correct code for reset() is as follows:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.newQuestion = angular.copy(tempQuestion);

    $scope.forms.newQuestion.$setPristine();
    $scope.forms.newQuestion.$setUntouched();

    $scope.attempted = false;

  };
```

Here is the modified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5UHs1tZ19Q2vxN0iFUGR?p=preview)

Comment: a minor little nit-pick; I would have used form.$submitted instead of "attempted" like you have in your plunker.

Answer (score 3):

Check your console and you'll see some errors. `setPristine()` does not exist on the object `forms`, as your form name is `forms.newQuestion`. Additionally, the function is `$setPristine()`. To rid the form of error messages on reset, you can just reset your `attempted` flag to be false, as that will cause your `ng-class` expression evaluations to be false.

You will want something like:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.newQuestion = angular.copy(tempQuestion);

    $scope.forms.newQuestion.$setPristine();
    $scope.forms.newQuestion.$setUntouched();
    $scope.attempted = false;
};
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PqCVayHTXDlHNufBvrwE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you - I rushed the Plunker example and had previously tried within my application $setPristine() but it wasn't working. It seems $setUntouched could be commented out too.